# why UserProcessorTime don't give the same value for the same executions

Tags: c#, .net, performance, process, measurement

I'm measuring just cpu time of the a method but it give me different time why ?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
TimeSpan start = Process.GetCurrentProcess().UserProcessorTime;
testFunction(100000);
TimeSpan end = Process.GetCurrentProcess().UserProcessorTime;
Console.WriteLine(end-start);
}
```

Comment: How much different are they?

Comment: You can expect the first time to be slower due to the JIT (Just-In-Time) compiler, e.g. ([1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6)) or ([2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6)). But as @blind.wolf says - how different *are* they?

Comment: Similar problem as before, the resolution of that timer is not very good.  It is only accurate to +/- 0.016 seconds.  Code normally runs a *lot* faster than that.  Use the Stopwatch class instead.  And you must run the test many times, only take the median of the measurement as a rough indication.  And consider using a profiler.

Comment: @HansPassant if i use StopWatch i'll not be able to calculate just cpu time but it wil give me also time of process in background which will make wrong my value

Comment: @WaiHaLee the result are lik 904.8058
920.4059
920.4059
889.2057
904.8058
920.4059
920.4059
920.4059
920.4059
920.4059

Comment: There is just no point in assuming that your program will ever run without "process in background".  All computers run processes in the background.  If you try to find the happy number then you just have a result that you can *never* reproduce.  This is the basic reason why you must run the test multiple times and take the median, it gets rid of outliers.

Comment: @Omega These results look quite similar so reasons why are already written in answer below.

Comment: @HansPassant I Already run the the test multiple times and get the median but always the median is different for the next execution for the same test.

Comment: That is entirely normal.  Stop looking for a better result, you have one that's accurate to +/- a handful of percent.  Good enough.

Comment: Why it's normal if we run the same code so the code will be executed in same cycle why then we have different values

Comment: @blind.wolf so if u ngen install xxx.exe i'll get same values or what ?

Comment: @Omega To get same result, you have to create that process with higher priority, than even OS, which is not possible (at least it should no be). Then there won't be process switching and your program will run without any interruption. This is pretty deep hardware thing, messing with processor cache updates, memory paging, interrupts, OS,...

Comment: @blind.wolf yes i know but the method GetCurrentProcess().UserProcessorTime return just the cpu time mean just whe nthe process is in cpu not like stopwatch

Comment: @HansPassant why this method return just the cpu time and we have also different i execution time ?

Comment: Everybody keeps telling you that code execution time is not consistent.  About time you take their word for it.  Google "Intel turbo boost" to learn more.

Comment: @Omega Yeah, it measure time of process spent actually processing. It's not instruction count. Processor will stall when caches are updating just because it's not long enough to actually switch process (which would cause even more cashe updates), but it measure time and not count. Instruction count should be same.

Comment: Why instruction count shoold be same i think it's better if we know the insruction count durring execution. their is any way to know how we can mesure the instruction count using profiler or some thing else.

Comment: Instruction count should be same, because the program itself is same. Each line of source code is transformed into few (or even few thousands) instructions. Because C# use JIT compiler and other more advanced things, sometimes, there can be different binaries each run. Number of instructions is meaningless, because especially read and write instructions takes different ammount of time depending on how deep in cache/RAM are needed data. There is only a few registers in CPU, so nearly everything is in RAM and cache.

Answer (score 2):

Function execution time depends on a lot of things: number of running processes at current time(which can be changed during loop execution), priority of your process(which as i know also can be changed), OS interrupts during function execution, RAM (for example RAM page fault) etc. So it's nothing strange if execution time differs a little from time to time.

Comment: it's why i'm using Process.GetCurrentProcess().UserProcessorTime and not StopWatch to calculate the cpu time but still the problem

Comment: @Omega The main contributors to the time are page faults and cache updates. This cannot be erased, because cache and pages are often changed when processes are changed